# Problems loging in after dealing with video drivers and black screen

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, 13.10, nvidia, gui

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop alongside windows 8.1. I have a Nvidia GeForce GT 645M video card on it and was having black screen on boot issues. so I installed the  xorg-edgers Nvidia drivers. After this fix I could get to the login screen, however whenever I would try to log in I get blank desktop screen with no interface and a warning saying "System program problem detected Do you want to report the problem now?"  and  If I log in as a guest I get a desktop screen with no interface.

Comment: If you can get to a Terminal prompt,  `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules` will remove the nvidia drivers, reset the X session settings and load the default `nouveau` drivers to let you have a working GUI.

Comment: I will convert that to an answer for you. Glad that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get to a Terminal prompt or Recovery Console,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

will remove the Nvidia drivers;

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

will reset the X session settings; and

```
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

will load the default nouveau drivers to let you have a working GUI. A reboot may be required, or try `service lightdm start` to get to the login screen.