# System is freezing (or getting stuck) frequently, while working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia

My system is Dell XPS L502X, with NVIDIA graphics card 525M. For your notice, it is different from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076) and [not completely related to this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431963/problems-loging-in-after-dealing-with-video-drivers-and-black-screen).

I was having problem of black screen after opening the Ubuntu 14.04. To get out of it
I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04.

After re-installing and adding NVIDIA drivers, system is getting freezed, frequently. So only option left is to press,<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>

[image: Already selected the option, while installation]

Comment: Could you ask about one problem at time. The errors with `apt-get` have their solution, the problems with the login has another solutions, the problems after installing the Nvidia drivers, another, etc. Instead ask a question per problem.

Comment: @Braiam Read **NB** ,it contains all the information. Installed NVIDIA.

Comment: I read that, still why you include the other problems? Focus your question in **one issue** at time.

Comment: Did you run 'sudo apt-get install nvidia-current'?

Comment: open "Additional Drivers" and install this one `Using X.OrgX server - Nouveau displary driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)` I had the same problem, it's related to Nvidia diver.

Comment: @saptarshinag I have already done that, problem is occurring afterwards.

Comment: Now, what you want to fix?

Comment: System freezes frequently, so, how to get out of this problem, once and for all.

Comment: Ok then try to activate the drivers.Go to Dash->additional drivers.A window will come select each of the drivers and click on activate.Remember activate one driver at a time(i.e.,activate a driver and then see if your problem persists or not,if persists then proceed one by one similarly.If problem solved after activating a driver then no need to proceed).

Comment: I have already selected it, after ubuntu installation(then restart, all those things), freezing is random, so difficult to say, when will happen.

Comment: maybe you should clean your hardware? is there a lot of dust in your machine?

Comment: I think you've tried the other versions available? I was getting problems with nvidia too, but they were gone after changing the package.

Comment: @Huskell How to go about it, help me in this matter.

Comment: @lavkush Well, just select another of the options in the window you posted and click apply changes, a little bar will show in the lower right, when it's done reset the PC. Mine was the (proprietary, tested), then I've changed to (proprietary only) NOT legacy (last option in your SS). My PC is exactly the same and have the same video card, I'm hopefully thinking it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's 100% related to the video driver? You could try the following to speed up your computer, too:

- Install the packages *preload* and *prelink*. These take certain actions to make the system faster.

  Execute `sudo apt-get install prelink preload` in a terminal.
- Reduce Swap usage. The default *swappiness* value is 60, which may be too high.

  Open the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` and set the swappiness parameter:
  `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf` in a terminal.
  New line at the end: `vm.swappiness = 10`, then another linebreak, save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

If you apply these changes, your computer should get faster after a reboot.

For your touchpad, you should ask a new question, since this is another problem.

Comment: My problem is related is to Drivers only, as when I selected my Graphics driver to Intel, my laptop was not able to restart, so got stuck on a black screen. If this won't harm my system(pardon me, for the ignorance), I will go ahead to implement them.

Comment: Those changes may only harm your system if you do a typo at `vm.swappiness = 10`. Otherwise they are safe.

Comment: Can this problem be, because of system is using NVIDIA extansivley, so slowing down. So if unnecessary use can be stopped.

Comment: Do I need to add like this, #vm.swappiness = 10

Comment: This will work, you will be the owner of the bounty.

Comment: @lavkush no, without the `#`. this would make the line a comment and therefore useless.

Comment: After that also, it won't work